# yaml unmarshal errors while uploading ConcourseCI pipeline

Tags: concourse

I tried to upload a ConcourseCI Pipeline to my Concourse Server using

```
fly -t <my_target> sp -p my_pip -c pipeline.yml -l creds.yml
```

But the upload terminates with the following error message:

```
fly -t local-docker sp -p siemens -c build/paas_ci_cd.yml -l config/credentials.yml
error: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 44: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 90: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 136: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 182: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 228: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 274: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 320: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 366: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 412: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 458: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 504: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 550: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 571: cannot unmarshal !!str `go-buil...` into []string
  line 597: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 643: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 689: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 735: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 781: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 827: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 873: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 919: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 965: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 1008: cannot unmarshal !!str `bosh up...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
  line 1032: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig
```

I already pasted my `pipeline.yml` into a yaml validator without any error complains. The pipeline was generated using erb templates. The lines which produce the error messages show now indentation problems or missing variables.

Comment: It might be valid YAML, but it is not the YAML that concourse is expecting. Please share one of the definitions it is complaining about.

Comment: Finally i found it. Indeed it was a problem with the yaml. The task definition was wrong since i was not filling out the run variable correctly. 

I guess it would be very helpful if concourse reports a more specific error with the task in this case.

Comment: What would be a better error message?

Comment: `line 44: cannot unmarshal !!str `bash he...` into atc.TaskRunConfig`
The first thing that bothered me was that the line 44 was not causing the error at all and after finding the error i still couldn't make sense about this error.

If there is something wrong with the Specification i would expect something like ConcourseConfigError, or perhaps TaskConfigError. Ideally it could tell me which variable is wrong e.g. in my case the run variable of the task definition.

Comment: I had a similar issue but it was not easy to fix since the parsing error is not very descriptive and nor did it state what error I made, but what error the parser encountered